# loop through json file, order by date (custom field) and show max 4 items

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, loops, each

Hi i try to make a function so i can loop through a json (wordpress json api) file contains 100 items. I only want to show 4 and i only want to show the 4 items from today. So the function must check the date of today and loop through the 100 items searching for the calendar items (mbwpc-start) and show the 4 items most near in de feature form today..

i hope make my self clear.

**the json file:**

http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/api/get_recent_posts/?count=100&post_type=mbwpc_event

**the function i have now, but that doesn't work:**

```
function showAgenda(){


        var wpAPI =  'http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/api/get_recent_posts/?count=150&post_type=mbwpc_event';

          $.getJSON(wpAPI, function(result) {

              var html = [];
              var count = 0;

              $.each( result.posts, function( i, item ) {

                var date = new Date(item["custom_fields"]["mbwpc-start"]*1000);

                if(item["custom_fields"]["mbwpc-start"]*1000 > Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000))
                {         

                    var html = '<li class="span12"><div class="thumbnail"><h4>' + item.title + '</h4><p>' + item.content.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '') + '</p>Datum: ' + date.toLocaleDateString() + '</div></li>';

                    $( ".left>.thumbnails" ).append(html);

                } // end if time from today

                // show max 4 items

                if (count == 3) {return false;}
                count++;

               }); // end each

           }); // end getjson

        } // end function
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? does it error? if so how? Doe sit just not interpret the data the way you want? please give us a bit more, so we don't have to look everywhere :D

Comment: it doesn't give an error but the each function only shows the 4 first items in stead of 4 items from today so the if function not working

Comment: the app in function you can see here: http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/napp/

Comment: So your criteria are (1) show most recent items first (2) only show items from today and (3) only show up to N items.  Is that correct?

Comment: @slashingweapon yes that's correct, the each function with max 4 items works but i tried to build a check from today functionality with the if function but that doesn't work:(. The json file is orderd by the date that a item is submitted but i want to order on the event start date (mbwpc-start in the json file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first task is to sort your array.  You can pass a custom comparison function to the `sort()` command to sort an array by any criteria you like.  The function has to return an integer: zero means the two values are equal, a positive result means the left argument should be sorted first, and a negative value means the right argument should be sorted first.  In this case, we parse the `mbwpc-start` field as an int, and then subtract the two values.

```
// first, you must sort your items by the desired criteria, 
// mbwpc-start descending
result.posts.sort( function(left,right) {
    return parseInt(right["custom_fields"]["mbwpc-start"]) - parseInt(left["custom_fields"]["mbwpc-start"]);
});
```

The next issue is your date comparisons.  You are creating your date objects correctly, but there is an easier way to compare them.  The JavaScript Date object has a handy function `toDateString()` which formats a date object as just the date.  We can use that to detect whether the mbwpc-start date is the same as today's date.

```
var today = new Date();
today = today.toDateString(); // "Thu Dec 19 2013"
```

Now it should be easy to loop through the list of posts looking for today's items, and stop when we hit our limit.

```
var itemCount = 0;

$.each(result.posts, function(i, item) {
    var postDate = new Date(item["custom_fields"]["mbwpc-start"]*1000);
    if ( postDate.toDateString() == today ) {
        // build your HTML and add it to your document
        // ...

        // Count, and break the loop if necessary
        if (++itemCount >= 4)
            return false;   // break the loop
    }
});
```

Comment: thanx for the code and the explanation of it:) make much clear :-) I tried it and it works! One thing i probably not explained well is the follow: This solution only shows the posts of today but it should also show the post in the feature for example the calendar items (mbwpc-start) from tomorrow and the coming week. Because it could be that there is no calendar item (mbwpc-start) today and then the function shoud display the items from tomorrow. The max of 4 is because the display has no more space for more items ;)

Comment: The problem is this part "if ( postDate.toDateString() == today ) {" this should not be equal of today but equal of greater but i tried >= but that doesn't work :(